# Server/Client program for data transfer. What is the professional, right way to do it?

Tags: c++, ssl, protocols, communication

For my scientific collaboration, I wrote a C++ server/client (terminal server for linux, and cross-platform GUI client using Qt) that is mainly meant to transfer data from multiple clients around the world to store it on one server for analysis (pretty much like LIGO and Virgo that caught gravitational waves). For the communication low-level protocol I used [boost::asio::ssl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/ssl.html).

**The "odd" part**: In my programs, I created my own half-duplex messaging protocol between the server and the client from scratch. The messaging was in string form containing the version of the protocol, endianness of the computer, length of the message, type of the message (login/file/error/etc...), an MD5 hash for verification of the completeness of the transferred data. I got highly criticized on Stackoverflow chat when I said I did this. The part that got specially criticized is: Writing my own messaging protocol.

Now I created this, and I know there should be better protocols that are already written that I shouldn't rewrite it from scratch. However, I wanted to learn how to do this myself, and I did, and the program works, and my collaboration is satisfied, and the sky is blue with birds singing.

**My question:** If I am to rewrite this program again, what kind of libraries should I use? I'm looking for a protocol, using which I can send messages/data and get the server to respond with messages/data, including username/password to authenticate the user before any communication is transferred? How would you have done it?

PS: Please consider this question coming from a beginner in writing network and internet wide programs. And please don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating your own protocol, and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way you did it, judging by your limited description. You're already using a well-known library and there is no reason to switch from it. Where is this criticism? And why would you contemplate reimplementing working code?

Comment: If off the shelf, open source and maintained code is available that fully supports your needs then writing your own seems a waste of time - time better spend on the real research task that you have. However, if it is for learning or because the available code/protocols do not serve your needs, I don't see any problem writing our own. However, be warned that it typically requires a major effort to write and maintain a high quality protocol.

Comment: @EJP I'm asking for the future. Although I'm a physicist, but I'm following a programming career and would like to know the "right" way to do it for other application. The criticism I got long time ago when I once asked about a memory leak I had. Sorry I can't refer to it as I can't find it right now.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that you might have investigated XML,  JSON, etc., but otherwise it is difficult to understand what was being criticised, and I don't agree with the comment that writing a high quality application protocol requires a major effort. But I agree that you should get on with physics.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the suggestions. I'll keep these ideas in mind! Actually it was Stackoverflow chat, not a question. That question is from a different problem actually, but similar.